# Why does the LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized method take so long?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

When we did a performance test of our MVC4 application it showed that the main view where a whole list of items is loaded from a database and displayed to the user has a very slow method.

[image: Slow]

The `global.asax` takes up about 50% of the resources and the `EnsureInitialized` the largest part of it.

Why can this be (I do not display code now since I have no idea where to look yet) and how can this method be made more efficiently?

Comment: What type is T (_initializer) ? And how does the ctor look?

Comment: @Matten It is of type SimpleMemberShipInitializer.

Comment: ctor is the term for Constructor, when you look at the `IL` code constructor will be listed as `ClassName.ctor()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application_Start` only runs once when the app starts. Not per page.

`EnsureInitialized` might take long in case your type takes a long time to construct or if the lock is contended. Drill down in the profiler to find out more.